# Xamarin Integrating Platform Specific Components into Cross Platform Code

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, loading

I have a simple cross platform app written in Xamarin with VS. All the UI is built in a shared (portable) class so it's written once (using Xamarin Forms) and covers both Android and iOS.

I now just want to add simple loading HUD and I cannot see any good cross platform HUDs. They're all just either written for iOS or Android. I just want to know how I can add a component to the Android and iOS project and access that from the shared class. i.e. Have a method in my shared class called ShowLoading() which loads the iOS component on iOS and android in Android (funny that).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Dependancy Service](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to access platform specific code from your common code.

I would also recommend having a look at the [BT Progress HUD](http://components.xamarin.com/view/btprogresshud) component (for iOS), and the [And HUD](http://components.xamarin.com/view/andhud) component (for android) for your loading hud. They can be used together in a cross platform manner, via the XHUD API.

Comment: Hi Chris, That worked but i'm half way there. I've got the ANDHud component for the Android project. Its wanting an "Activity/Context" in the show method. How am I able to pass this down from the shared project?

Comment: I had the same problem a few days ago! What I ended up doing, was creating a public static field in the MainActivity.cs [public static AndroidActivity Instance;]. On create, I then set this activity [Instance = this;]. I then use this instance/activity when required. This is slightly hacky, and there are other ways to get the context, but this is probably the most easy and useful. This is sort of the result of how xamarin forms handles your activity, and your codes decoupling from it, but does manage to solve the problem.

Comment: No problem! If you find a cleaner way, please let me know!

Comment: Hi Chris, while i've got you do you know of any good cross platform rest service classes that can use in the shared project. i.e. Like RestSharp for all platforms?

Comment: I can't say I have used any, sorry. There was a portable build of restsharp done recently though, so that might be a good start spot for you. https://www.nuget.org/packages/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable/

Comment: You could also use HttpClient, it is Portable.

Comment: According to the Android example in the DependencyService documentation, there is a way to access the context via Forms.Context. I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a github project for cross-platform progress hud (it uses ANDHud and BTProgressHud under the covers). https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms

According to the examples, you could do something as simple as:

```cs
    private readonly IUserDialogService dialogService;

    public ICommand Alert {
        get {
            return new Command(async () => {
                await dialogService.AlertAsync("Test alert", "Alert Title", "CHANGE ME!");
                this.Result = "Returned from alert!";
            });
        }
    }
```